# Applying Filters on Database Populated JTable

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, performance

I have a **Java** application that shows the content of a single table in **PostgreSQL**, assume a table of movies. The content of this table is queried into an **ArrayList** and the elements of the list are shown in a **JTable**. I want to apply some filters on this movie catalogue so that my table will only show the elements satisfying the filter criteria. These are simple filters similar to:

- Movie names that contain the given substring
- Movies that are directed by the selected director
- Movies that are released after/before the given year
- Movies that have more than the given IMDB score

Basically, all filters can be applied using simple SQL queries. As far as I can see, I have two choices here:

1. Query all movies into the list and then programmatically apply the filter. In this one, the data will only be queried at the beginning (assuming there are no changes on the database) but it consumes too much storage.
2. Each time a filter is applied, make a new SQL query and only store the movies that satisfy the given filter criteria in the list. This one has less storage need but it makes a new query each time a filter is applied.

I would like to know which one of these methodologies is the better option and would the situation be any different if there were updates on the movie database (which there are). If there is another option, I also would like to know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arguably, *which one of these methodologies is the better option* may be an opininated question which is off-topic on StackOverflow. I would go with #2. Java SQL APIs are fast in runs so number of query calls is not taxing.

Comment: Post your actual table definition, some sample data - as text **no images**, and the output expected. It *may* be possible to generalize a single query for option 2.